# Formulario funciona con GET pero no con POST en el controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Estoy trabajando con Symfony 4 y estoy tratando de enviar un formulario por el método POST a una función dentro de un Controller, pero me sale un error diciendo que el Controller no existe. Si lo envío por el método GET anda todo bien, o sea, el path esta correcto.

El Route lo defino en la misma función del Controller así:

```
/**
 * @Route("/mi_controller/my_function/", name="mi_route")
 */
public function mi_funciton(){....
```

Después en la vista creo el formulario así:

```
<form action="{{ path('mi_route') }}" method="post" >
```

Si cambio el method a GET me direcciona bien, pero con POST me dice Controller indefinido. ¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Y si añade el método en su controlador ? `@Route("/mi_controller/my_function/", name="mi_route")  @Method( "POST")`

Comment: Ya lo hice y tampoco funciona

Comment: Y con las llaves? `@Method({"POST"})`

Comment: Siii ahora funciono!! gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Según la [Documentación](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-method) puede especificar la anotación `@Method` a su controlador para especificar el método `HTTP`

```
/**
 * @Route("/mi_controller/my_function/", name="mi_route")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function mi_funciton(){....
```

Comment: Ya lo probé poniendo eso pero tampoco funciona

Comment: @GermanKinen Actualicé mi respuesta, faltaban las llave en el método. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debería de funcionar sin ningún problema indicando en el formulario que los datos deben ir por POST.

Sería interesante si nos mostrases como intentas recoger esos datos que vienen por POST en el controlador. Yo siempre lo hago de esta manera

```
public function mi_funciton(Request $request){
    $request->get('name-del-imput');
}
```

o directamente utilizo los componentes de formulario de Symfony. Ahí tienes toda la documentacion: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#content_wrapper